# Searching good Debugger for C++

Tags: c++, debugging

i was wondering if there was a good debugger you can recommend for C++.
thanks for helping

Comment: Which development environment do you use.

Comment: ddd under linux or use VS 2008 Express edition on windows(it is for free).
For memoryleaks under linux you can use valgrind from: valgrind.org.

Comment: You want some tool for performance analysis or memory analysis etc or just some tool for debugging purposes

Comment: you really need to state what development environment you use - if it's text-editor + shell + commandline tools, you'll need to specify your OS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i recommend emacs + gdb. best combination ever.

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

Whats wrong with Visual studio unless you use linux.

ANyway my suggestion is Visual studio.
But this also depends on what sort of a c++ project you work with.

Answer (score 2):

General answer: use whatever debugger comes with your IDE - something that knows about your project structure will help you *immensely* when navigating, setting breakpoints, inspecting variables, evaluating expressions, and possibly offering features like edit-and-continue instead of forcing a recompile. Personally, I find Visual Studio to have a pretty darn decent debugger.

If you *don't* use an IDE, your options are limited... especially if you want symbolic debugging. Your options will pretty much boil down to GDB (with or without frontends), or WinDBG on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two choices :

- the visual studio debugger if you're under Visual (just press F5)
- GDB, and its various user interfaces (this goes from a harsh Emacs mode to QtCreator integration

Answer (score 0):

For Linux you could also try [Zero](http://www.zero-bugs.com/2.0/product_intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

Intel has a debugger called [idb](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/cpp/lin/idb/olh/welcome_app_mid2.html) which is nice and works rather well.

Answer (score 0):

```
code blocks
```

Code::Blocks is a free C, C++ and Fortran IDE built to meet the most demanding needs of its users. It is designed to be very extensible and fully configurable.

Finally, an IDE with all the features you need, having a consistent look, feel and operation across platforms.

Built around a plugin framework, Code::Blocks can be extended with plugins. Any kind of functionality can be added by installing/coding a plugin. For instance, compiling and debugging functionality is already provided by plugins!

Special credits go to darmar for his great work on the FortranProject plugin, bundled since release 13.12.

We hope you enjoy using Code::Blocks!